# Мул - этимология

Tags: этимология

Название "лошак" - понятно: ЛОШадь_иШАК. А вот откуда взяли мул - гибрид осла и кобылы?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

А Мул  от лат. mūlus — результат скрещивания, помесь ( осла и кобылы). Термин «мул» первоначально применяли к отпрыску любых двух животных разных видов — в настоящее время называемого «гибридом». А лошак - помесь ослицы и жеребца.

От мула произошло и слово  мулат - потомок от брака представителей европеоидной расы и негроидной, от испанского mulato.  По другой версии, этимология слова восходит к арабскому «муваллад» – нечистокровный араб.Но смысл один - помесь.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%F3%EB